# Flash - streaming video

Tags: flash, actionscript, video

What code should I use in AS2.0 if I wish to make my swf application play streaming video.

Right now I am using the `NetStream` interface, but as I realize it is only capable to buffer the video from the very beginning.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetStream buffers from the current frame onwards.  You can use [seek()](http://flash-reference.icod.de/NetStream.html#seek%28%29) to jump to any position in the video.